# If user input doesn't meet conditions, return message

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

So I'm really new to Java, and what I'm trying to do is let the user input a keyword, which will be passed to different conditions. If the keyword starts with "c", it will execute cmethod. If the keyword starts with "n", it will execute nmethod. 
The problem is, I also want to display a message if the user inputs neither something that starts with "c" or "n". Here's what I've been able to think through (I'm aware that this code won't work though)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This program can randomize characters or numbers.");
    System.out.println("Please input \"c\" for characters, and \"n\" for numbers. ");
    Scanner choices = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (choices.next().startsWith("c")) {
        cmethod();
    }

    else {
        nmethod();
    }

    //how do I execute the code below if none of the conditions are met?
    else {
        System.out.println("Keyword is wrong.");
    }
}
```

**EDIT :** Tried to use else if, but then for nmethod() to be executed, the user have to type in "n" twice.

Comment: where is `else if`

Comment: Replace the second else with an else-if, that check if the entered char was `n` ...

Comment: I suggest trying break your problem into steps... Step 1: Read the word. Step 2: Check for "c". Step 3: If not "c", check for "n", Step 4: Sysout. You will need to store your read value into a variable, because calling choices.next() two times will lead to funny results.

Comment: Regarding your edit, that's because you're prompting them again by calling `choices.next()` again. Store the result in a variable and then you can test it as many times as you need to.

Comment: @Eustion you replaced an important part of your question by "Problem solved", so your question and its answer don't really make sense anymore. You should keep the part where you said that you tried a `else if` and that you were reading two characters, as it was the real problem (calling `next()` twice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to extract `next()` to a variable. If you don't do it, `next()` will always return the current keyword and move on to the next one.
Additionally you have to use `else if` if you want to check for another keyword.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This program can randomize characters or numbers.");
    System.out.println("Please input \"c\" for characters, and \"n\" for numbers. ");
    Scanner choices = new Scanner(System.in);

    String keyword = choices.next();

    if (keyword.startsWith("c")) {
        cmethod();
    } else if (keyword.startsWith("n")) {
        nmethod();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Keyword is wrong.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally someone who gets it.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.

Comment: A lot of people went mad over the `else if` ^^
As a precision, the use of a switch could've been more logical, as it falls in the category of "applying different behaviors and getting a fallback case when none works"

Answer (score 2):

The `else` keyword is exactly what you need. What you should use to solve your problem is `else if`. To avoid reading another input between the `if`'s, just store `choices.next()` in a variable and call this variable instead in your `if`s statements.

```
String entry = choices.next();
if (entry.startsWith("c")) {
    cmethod();
}
else if (entry.startsWith("n")) {
    nmethod();
}
else {
    // default behaviour if wrong entry
}
```

The nmethod() will be called only if the input is not 'c' and is 'n', and if none of these conditions are met, it will enter the `else` part.

Comment: You can't have multiple `else` statements. Middle line needs to be `else if`.

Comment: Guys... He does NOT want to check the FIRST keyword against "c" and then the SECOND against "n"...

Comment: Now your answer perfect

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have some working solutions provided here, it seems weird that no one spoke about the really easy `switch` statement.

Basically:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This program can randomize characters or numbers.");
    System.out.println("Please input \"c\" for characters, and \"n\" for numbers. ");
    Scanner choices = new Scanner(System.in);

    switch(choices.next().charAt(0)) {
        case 'c':
            cmethod();
            break;
        case 'n':
            nmethod();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Keyword is wrong.");
    }
}
```

This join the other answers on the fact that the `next()` function is only evaluated once.

Comment: Was wondering how to do this with `switch` statement. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: Using switch-case

```
String s =choices.next();
char first = s.charAt(0);

switch(first){
  case 'c': cmethod(); break;
  case 'n':nmethod(); break;
  default : System.out.println("Keyword is wrong.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection where you can pass method name and if method exist then it will be found otherwise it will throw exception where you can display message.

```
java.lang.reflect.Method method;
try {
     method = this.getClass().getMethod(methodName, param1.class, 
 param2.class, ..);
 } catch (SecurityException e) { ... }
catch (NoSuchMethodException e) { ... }
```

Try sample where put correct and wrong method name in below test example.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Object obj = new Test();

    java.lang.reflect.Method method;
    try {
        method = obj.getClass().getMethod("tryone1");
        System.out.println("Found");
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        System.out.println(" SecurityException Found");
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        System.out.println("Not Found");
    }

}

public void tryone() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void trytwo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Do customize above example as per your need. Such as if c comes as argument then String methodname= arg[0]+"method" and pass as method parameter name in getMethod("tryone1") method.

Comment: Think about future where you want to run any available method and show error if not found.

Comment: I believe you didn't understand his question. He has only two options he must chose from, and has no need to dynamically adapt to the parameters.
R

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This program can randomize characters or numbers.");
    System.out.println("Please input \"c\" for characters, and \"n\" for numbers. ");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try{
    String s = br.readLine();
    if (s.startsWith("c")) {
        System.out.println("c");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    if (s.startsWith("n")){
        System.out.println("n");
        System.exit(1);
    }else {
    System.out.println("Keyword is wrong.");
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Worked For me, hope it does for you.